Does passing class variables Stop Paralellization in Numba?
I have a wrapper method to call a Numba-compatible function. In the code below, the method get_neighbours_wrapper() is just a wrapper to call the Numba function get_neighbours_Numba().
I want to call the neighbours.get_neighbours_wrapper(point) on a separate thread and that's why I am expecting parallelization.
Even though I see some performance enhancement
by making the function Numba compatible, but I am not sure if it running in parallel (most likely not). I doubt that the caller function i.e. get_neighbours_wrapper() tries to access the member variables of the class and therefore probably stops the real parallelization (due to GIL lock?).
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def get_neighbours_Numba(points: np.ndarray, num_neighbors: int):

    for point in points:
        distances = np.zeros(num_neighbors)
        neighbours_indices_xy = np.zeros((num_neighbors, 2))
        
        ## There is some further code, but not relevant for the question
    
    return  distances


class Neighbours:
    def __init__(self, xy_points: np.ndarray, num_neighbors: int):
        self.xy_points = xy_points
        self.num_neighbors = num_neighbors

    def get_neighbours_wrapper(self, point: np.ndarray):
        distances = get_neighbours_Numba(self.xy_points, self.num_neighbors)   # QUESTIONS: Can using class variables STOP PARALLELIZATION?
        return distances
    

# Example usage
xy_points = np.random.rand(100, 2)
num_neighbors = 6
neighbours = Neighbours(xy_points, num_neighbors)
point = np.random.rand(2)
distances = neighbours.get_neighbours_wrapper(point)
print(distances)

Question: Are passing class variables Stopping Parallelization in Numba? If yes, what could be the solution?

The short answer is "no". You don't pass a class variable. You use a class variable to access an object, and the object is passed to the function. the get_neighbors_Numba functions has no idea how the object you passed to it came to be, whether it was accessed from an attribute or not. And it would be totally irrelevant in any case. In any case, it isn't clear why you expect any parallelization here, I am not super familiar with numba,

@juanpa.arrivillaga: I want to call the neighbours.get_neighbours_wrapper(point) on a separate thread and that's why I am expecting parallelization. Thanks for pointing it out, will update my question.

The GIL would not be released here - njit() has nogil=False set by default. See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/jit-compilation.html


I want to call the neighbours.get_neighbours_wrapper(point) on a separate thread and that's why I am expecting parallelization.

Note that in CPython threads must lock objects with the GIL so to protect the interpreter. This locking mechanism tends to prevent any speed up since threads eventually run in sequential unless the GIL is released for the computational part.
Numba @njit functions release the GIL so multiple njitted function calls in multiple threads can truly run in parallel. The same applies with Numba njitted functions and other function releasing the GIL. That being said, note that releasing the GIL means you are responsible for the code not to contain any race condition. Otherwise, the result is undefined (e.g. crash of the interpreter). Also please note that no CPython object can be accessed in parts of the code releasing the GIL though this is already the case for njitted Numba function.
Numba threads can only execute code not using CPython objects. Put it differently, prange loops cannot operate on CPython objects and the GIL is always released when they are executed.

I am not sure if it running in parallel

Numba functions are sequential by default (at least CPU ones) unless you explicitly specify they are parallel. This can be done with both the parallel=True JIT flag and using prange on loops (instead of usual range). The JIT flag alone does not automatically parallelize your code but can execute some basic Numpy functions in parallel.
Just to be clear, your current code is fully sequential. There are no threads spawned.

I doubt that the caller function i.e. get_neighbours_wrapper() tries to access the member variables of the class and therefore probably stops the real parallelization (due to GIL lock?).

Numba njitted functions are split in two parts : a wrapper function and a native function. The wrapper function is responsible for converting CPython objects to native ones (and the other way) while native functions do the actual computing work. The wrapper function also release the GIL before calling the native function and lock the GIL back after the native function has been executed. The GIL do not need to be locked to access variables of native types.
In practice, here, Numba will convert self.xy_points to an internal/Numba-specific native Numpy array data structure, and self.num_neighbors to a native integer. Once converted, the internal Numpy data structure still reference the same shared Numpy array buffer in memory. This means data of the Numpy array object can be mutated in Numba functions (possibly by multiple threads when the GIL is released). When the inner code of get_neighbours_Numba is executed, the GIL is released for the current thread. If you run get_neighbours_wrapper from two different CPython thread concurrently, then only the inner code of get_neighbours_Numba can run in parallel. The rest of the code in get_neighbours_wrapper (implicit object conversion) will be locked and thus serialized. Note that a small fraction of the code spent locking the GIL can significantly decrease the scalability of a parallel code. For more information about this, see Amdahl's_law.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I would like to read further about this topic (Numba-based optimization and parallelization) to better understand the do  & don't. Do you have any suggestion, on how can somebody obtain information on this topic, any book or other literature? The Numba documentation is not helpful for me as I need to start with the basics.
